# Enumerate child elements of a ListBoxItem

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, listboxitem

The actual visuals are dictated by a DataTemplate. In runtime, how can I iterate through all the visual elements of a ListBoxItem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have a reference to one of the `ListBoxItem`s in the list, you can use the [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx) class to enumerate the visual tree of it.

Otherwise, if you have a reference to one of the items displayed in the `ListBox`, try calling [ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.containerfromitem.aspx) off of the `ListBox` (note that the item must be displayed for this to work, since the `ListBox` generally only keeps items that are visible in memory).

Comment: There is an example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx

Comment: This answer does not work for me with an ItemsControl. After inserting a new item at index 0, I can do the following:

var presenter = (ContentPresenter)_itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0);

Unfortunately, VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(presenter) is zero!

Comment: I made a quick test app, and that worked for me. You might want to post a new question and provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

Keep aside the reason why you need to do so....

I think you need the [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx) class for this.